# Django-compressor not finding blocks to compress in a GitHub Action

Tags: django, django-compressor

I have a Django project that's using [django-compressor](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to minify and concatenate CSS files, using offline compression. I haven't yet put it on a server, but when I run `manage.py compress` in a GitHub Action, before running tests, it can't find the `{% compress %}` block, even though it can find the template containing them.

I have a single template that uses CSS files, `templates/myapp/layouts/base.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load compress static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  {% compress css file global %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'oohdir/css/global/variables.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'oohdir/css/global/reset.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'oohdir/css/global/form.css' %}">
    <!-- etc -->
  {% endcompress %}
```

When running the site locally I can have these Django settings:

```
DEBUG = False
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
```

and when I run `manage.py compress` it generates a single CSS file, as expected, in `static_collected/CACHE/CSS/`. That file is linked in the HTML when I view pages in the browser (using `manage.py runserver --insecure`).

But when I run my GitHub Action many tests fail because of a missing file, which django-compressor didn't generate.

If I run `manage.py compress --verbosity 2` in the Action I can see it finds the correct template among all the others:

```
Found templates:
        ...
        myapp/inc/form_field.html
        myapp/layouts/base.html
        admin/tree_list.html
        ...
```

But it doesn't think there's anything to compress in it:

```
Compressing... done
Compressed 0 block(s) from 9 template(s) for 1 context(s).
```

That should be `1 block(s)`. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Dan's cheat sheet](https://cheat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django/compressor.html) I found the problem: In my GitHub Action I was running `manage.py compress` before `manage.py collectstatic` - thinking that `collectstatic` would need to collect the generated, compressed, CSS file(s).

But it needs to be the other way round, so that all the static files are collected in place before `compress` can do its work on them.

So now my tests step looks something like this:

```yaml
      - name: Run Tests
        run: |
          ./manage.py collectstatic --verbosity=0 --noinput
          ./manage.py compress --verbosity=0
          flake8 myproject
          black . --check
          coverage run ./manage.py test
        env:
          [all my env vars]
```